# How do I go about converting temperatures using C program in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

This is the formatted C program is called fahr_kel:

---

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>

 int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
 {
    if (argc < 3) 
 {
  std::cerr << "Usage:" << argv[0] << " arg1 arg2 \n"
  << "arg1 is the conversion type (1 or 2) \n "
  << "arg 2 is the temp to be converted" << std::endl;
  return 1;
 }
 // Assign the variables used in this program
 int temp, conv_temp, conv_type;

 // assign the input options to variables
 conv_type=atoi(argv[1]);
 temp=atoi(argv[2]);

 // convert the temps..
 // if the input number is 1, convert from Kelvin to Fahrenheit
 // if the input number is anything else, convert from Fahrenheit to Kelvin
 if (conv_type == 1)
 conv_temp = (((temp - 273) * 1.8) + 32);
 else  
 conv_temp = (((( temp - 32 ) * 5 ) / 9 ) + 273 );

 // print the data 
 printf ("       %3.1i                  %3.1i\n",temp,conv_temp);

 // end of main function 
 return 0;
 }
```

I need to manipulate this program from the user input in my bash script.

---

This is the data file I need to pass through the C program called project3.data:

```
 0
 32
 100
 212
 108
 1243
 3000
 85
 22
 2388
 235
```

---

This is the script I started called project3.bash.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo -n "Convert from  kelvin to fahrenheit(1) or fahreinheit to kelvin(2)"

 read choice 

 /home/username/project3/fahr_kel [ choice project3.data ]
```

I am only getting the first row for the output of the script.
0 and 256

The output needs to look like this:

```
 ---------------------- -----------------------
 Fahrenheit Temperature Kelvin Temperature
 --------------------- -----------------------
           0                  256
 ---------------------  -----------------------
           32                 273
 ---------------------- -----------------------
          100                 310
 ---------------------- -----------------------
          212                 373
 ---------------------- -----------------------
          108                 315
 ---------------------- -----------------------
          1243                945
 ---------------------- -----------------------
          3000                1921
 ---------------------- -----------------------
           85                  302
 ---------------------- -----------------------
           22                  268
 ---------------------- -----------------------
          2388                 1581
 ---------------------- -----------------------
          235                   385
 ---------------------- -----------------------
```

Comment: Are you trying to write a C program, a C++ program, or a shell script? it's not at all clear from your question as it stands

Comment: I'm sorry. I now realize it didn't make sense I tried to fix it.

Comment: I need to use the C program in my shell script  that will convert temperatures in the data file and then output them as shown.

Comment: (1) That’s a C++ program, not a C program.  `std::cerr <<` didn’t exist in C.  (2) What is the script supposed to do?  I ***guess*** you want it to ask the user which way the temperatures should be converted, and then process the numbers from the file.  Please say so explicitly; don’t make us guess.  (3) Think about it: What are the arguments to the C++ program?  (Two numbers.)  What arguments are you *passing* to the C++ program?  (A number and a file name.) See the problem?

Comment: @Scott The only issue I have now is that only the first row of what the output should look like shows up, I figured out the rest. Any ideas?

Comment: You think that’s the only issue you have? Here, do a couple of experiments for me.  Edit `project3.data` and change the first number to be *anything* other than 0, and run the script again.  Then rename `project3.data` to `project3.data.bak` and run the script again.  You’re not getting a row of output with a temperature of 0 because your script is reading the first line of `project3.data`; you’re getting a row of output with a temperature of 0 because your script is failing to work. Meanwhile, Vignesh has posted an answer explaining all of this.

Comment: [Same school project?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358816/linux-convert-fahrenheit-to-kelvin-and-vice-versa?rq=1) Wherein [a comment suggests maybe it's meant to be csh, not C](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358816/linux-convert-fahrenheit-to-kelvin-and-vice-versa?rq=1#comment637940_359036)...

Comment: @Scott Okay I asked this before vignesh answered. Thanks for the help Scott.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Wow it could be. Not sure who that is though.

Comment: @Jaruto As a veracity check, ensure that the input does not go below zero in case of "K ---> F" conversion, OTW be prepared for nonphysical results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ program converts temperatures as desired, and expects a temperature value as the second input argument. However, your bash script does not pass the temperature as input argument. Instead, it calls the c++ program with the *data filename as input argument*. This is not desired. You should call the c++ program using the input values themselves as argument; i.e. you need to modify the bash script as follows.

The necessary fix in the bash script is to call the c function once for every data line, and to add necessary formating. I show this below.

```
#!/bin/bash

inputFile="project3.data"

echo -n "Convert from  kelvin to fahrenheit(1) or fahreinheit to kelvin(2)"

read choice 
# run the following per input data line
#./fahr_kel [ choice project3.data ]
cmd="./fahr_kel $choice "

# print header
linePrint="------------------  ----------------"
echo $linePrint
echo "Fahrenheit Temperature Kelvin Temperature"
echo $linePrint

while read inputVal
do
      $cmd $inputVal
      echo $linePrint
done < "$inputFile"
echo $linePrint
```

Another way is to change the  c++ program to expect a file input instead of temperature input.

Comment: You need to change the header too based on the value of $choice.

Comment: @RakeshSharma I did that using if statement output is perfect, thanks. Would you happen to know how to capture the output of both options? I tried to run bash project3.bash 1 >> project3.output. But, it did not show correct output.

Comment: @Jaruto, That should work. What is the output you get?

Comment: @Vignesh No problem with the output it is perfect. I just need help to capture it and put it in another file.

Comment: @Jaruto To capture the o/p just add this line after the `# print header` line:  `exec 1>SCRIPT.LOG`